# C# List.Remove(item) glitch?

Tags: c#

Today, I came across a glitch in C# lists, or at least it looks like one to me, so I thought I'd ask. Here's the code:

```
// in main
List<Move> LM = new List<Move>();
LM.Add(new Move(4, 7));

// in Move
public Move(int ccc, int rrr)
{
  col = ccc;
  row = rrr;

  scr_check_duplicates();
}

public void scr_check_duplicates()
{
  foreach (Move M in Main.LM)
  {
    if (M.col == col && M.row == row)
      Main.LM.Remove(this);
  }
}
```

Well guess what? The Remove() wasn't doing anything! If you want to figure it out yourself, go ahead. Otherwise, here's the reason:

After tracing it around for a while, I believe it's because in the middle of the new Move() constructor, the object hasn't actually been added to the list just yet because it's still initializing.

Question is, is this a glitch or is C# intentionally made this way? It seems to me that if it just went ahead and added a new Move, and then called the constructor, it would work fine without breaking any conceivable code. Are there better ways to do what I want? Ideally I'd like to be able to remove immediate inside the constructor or any functions it calls.

Comment: Your code isn't a complete example.  Provide a *complete* example that can replicate your problem, and explain what you expect it to do and how that differs from what happens.

Comment: You might want to create a static add function to the class which adds to the List after checking for dups.

Comment: You can't remove an item in a `foreach` of the list, and `Remove(this)` smells.

Comment: There is no glitch in C# regarding this in my opinion, you just need to re-factor this piece of code to achieve your required goal.

Comment: +1 for code smell. I suggest you read about separation of concerns.

Comment: I guess just to pile on with everyone else, stay away from those global-like variable of `col` and `row`.  It's going to lead you to spaghetti code.  Those variables should just be passed to the check duplicate function as parameters.

Answer (score 5):

There is no glitch. Think about what executes first. Your code is the same as this...

```
// in main
List<Move> LM = new List<Move>();
Move move=new Move(4, 7);
LM.Add(move);
```

So the constructor runs fully **before** the item gets added to the list. Therefore, at the point you call `Main.LM.Remove(this);` the item isn't yet in LM and so there's nothing to remove.

In addition, you can't call Remove on a collection while you're inside a foreach block that's iterating over the collection.

Comment: You would never even execute `Main.LM.Remove(this);` because the if would evaluate to false. (Unless you tried to add it again later)

Comment: I'm thinking he provided us an incomplete example and there's actually many Move items added to LM. So at some point it's possible the if statement would evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to me that if it just went ahead and added a new Move, and then called the constructor

That's just not how it works.  In order to pass an object to `Add`, it has to have the instance.  Which is what you're creating when calling `new Move(...)`.  So in this construct, c'tor MUST run first, and Add afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above clarify why you get the behavior you do.

To handle it correctly, I suggest using a [HashSet](http://cplus.about.com/od/learnc/a/csharp-sets-and-hashset.htm).  It will prevent you from adding duplicate values.  You will need to override the .Equals and .GetHashCode methods on your object to tell the set the objects are equal.  However, this will keep your collection from containing duplicate values.